# What does `test-on-borrow` do?

Tags: database

What does it do? How does it work? Why am I supposed to test the database connection before "borrowing it from the pool"?

I was not able to find any related information as to *why* I should be using it. Just *how* to use it. And it baffles me.

Can anyone provide some meaningful definition and possibly resources to find out more?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"test-on-borrow" indicates that a connection from the pool has to be validated usually by a simple SQL validation query defined in "validationQuery". These two properties are commonly used in conjunction to make sure that the current connections in the pool are not stale (no longer connected to the DB actively as a result of a DB restart, or timeouts enforced by the DB, or whatever other reason that might cause stale connections). By testing the connections on borrow, the application can automatically reconnect to the DB using new connections (and dropping the invalid ones) without a manual restart of the app and thus preventing DB connection errors in the app.

You can find more information on jdbc connection pool attributes here:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes